# How to empty Recycle Bin using Java in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, file-handling, desktop, recycle-bin

Since Java Version 9, one can just move files to Recycle Bin, rather than deleting it permanently, using the

```java
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().moveToTrash(file)
```

method. But, I am also willing to know whether there is a way to Empty the Recycle Bin in Windows using Java 9 or higher versions, for some reasons in my Application?

Comment: I would not want applications to have that ability.  Users should decide when that happens.

Comment: Yes I accept that for few instances, but I am just interested to know whether there is a way to empty the Recycle Bin using Java 9+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's not supported and probably never should be